# Is there a difference between "tongue-tied" and "speechless"?

Tags: meaning, differences, word-usage

Earlier today, a student of mine was telling me a story about how his colleague, upon seeing him wearing an over-the-top jacket, was so *surprised* that she couldn't say anything.

Question: Which expression would you have said?

> "My colleague was ***tongue-tied***  when she saw me wearing such an extravagant jacket"
>    or
>   "My colleague was ***speechless*** when she saw me wearing such an extravagant jacket"

I'd always thought that the two were synonyms, but Merriam Webster defines *tongue-tied* as "unable to speak because you are nervous or shy" and *speechless* as "unable to speak because of anger, **surprise**, etc.", so I'd probably be more inclined to use *speechless* in this situation.

However, Random House Kernerman Webster's College Dictionary has a broader definition of *tongue-tied* ("unable to speak, as from shyness, embarrassment, or **surprise**"), which seems to suggest that *speechless* and *tongue-tied* are synonyms.

Your thoughts? How would you use *speechless* and *tongue-tied*?

Comment: I generally see "tongue-tied" used when the speaker is stammering or babbling, whereas "speechless" seems to be used when the speaker can't say anything at all.

Answer (score 4):

The two sentences have a slightly different denotation, and a significantly different connotation:

> My colleague was *tongue-tied* when she saw me wearing such an extravagant jacket.

This indicates to me that your colleague wanted to say something, but couldn't.  She was probably stammering over what she wanted to say, or couldn't get it out because she was nervous.

Because of the connection between *tongue-tied* and shyness or embarrassment, the phrase *tongue-tied* can also impart a romantic connotation.  For example, "The boy saw the pretty girl, but couldn't compliment her because he was tongue tied."

> My colleague was SPEECHLESS when she saw me wearing such an extravagant jacket.

This indicates to me that your colleague couldn't find the words to express what she wanted to say.  Either her surprise over seeing you in the jacket (or her anger/jealousy/etc. in seeing you in such and extravagent jacket) simply "took" the words right out of her.

Often times, "speechless" has a negative connotation, because of its connection to anger, jealousy, etc.  For example, "My mom was speechless when she heard me cuss out my grandmother."  In such a sentence, "tongue-tied" wouldn't be appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

Regardless of the definition (denotation), *tongue-tied* to me always has a connotation of social awkwardness: you get tongue-tied because of embarrassment, even if the emotion you're trying to express is one of surprise. *Speechlessness*, on the other hand, has no such connotation: if you're so surprised you're speechless, there's no component of embarrassment.

Another way to think about it is that *tongue-tied* refers to a self-imposed unwillingness to talk, albeit often a subconscious one: you're so worried about what others will think that you keep revising what you want to say, to the point that nothing comes out. If you're speechless, on the other hand, you don't care one whit for what others think, but the situation is so astounding that you just can't find the words to express what you feel.

Needless to say, I think *speechless* is the better choice for your extravagant jacket example.

Answer (score 0):

***Speechless*** almost always implies anger, or at least frustration, having been taken by surprise at what one has seen or heard. It could also perhaps mean 'rhetorically defeated for words'.

***Tongue-tied*** suggests a momentary verbal or mental impediment to speech, which could be caused by a variety of factors such as a stammer, ineffectiveness in public, embarrassment social awkwardness etc. It does not usually imply anger.

Comment: You can be "lost for words" when you are pleasantly or unexpectedly surprised; I think *speechless* is quite similar. It's more like *shock* rather than anger, I feel.

Comment: "When I saw the canyon for the first time, I was awestruck and speechless before its magnificence" or something similar works for me. No anger, no frustration.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I agree totally with 'lost for words', and it is how I would expect someone might describe their experience of 'seeing the canyon for the first time' per Amadan. But I still think 'speechless' usually implies anger or annoyance. It may be a British v American thing.

Comment: @Mari-LouA The OED doesn't help much. Among a plethora of different nuances for *speechless* it doesn't provide any example of its use more recent than 1915.

Comment: I'm not sure if it is a BrEng vs. AmEng thing. I've never been aware there was any difference in meaning or usage, I would still consider *to be under shock* and *too shocked for words* as a synonym for speechless. The rare times I have been struck dumb were nearly always a reaction to someone's outrageous (unpleasantly shocked) or extremely stupid statements/claims (disbelief, incredulity).

Comment: I'm only commenting because I do like your definitions but for that bit that suggests "speechlessness" is motivated by *anger* and *frustration*.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Let me put it like this, I would be reluctant to use the word *speechless* unless I wanted to express how angry I was about something - it wouldn't sound right. In all other instances I would use one of the other expressions.